# How to add a modifier to many key frames?

Tags: animation, modifiers, keyframes, select

I have an animated armature that is a person walking, but the animation is too short. I would like to add a cycles modifier to my final keyframes to repeat the motion, but there are way too many keyframes to reasonably add the modifier to each one individually. Is there a way to add a modifier to many keyframes at once?
Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, josh sanfelici, I will try that. Just out of curiosity though, is there a way to add a modifier to multiple keyframes at once?

Comment: I updated my answer.

Comment: Okay, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can copy and paste all needed keyframes all at once in the dopesheet or action editor, or you can use the repeat function in the Nonlinear Animation Editor.

Anyway, to answer the question, you can add a modifier to one channel, tweak its values then click its copy button, then select all the needed channels and click paste button.

[image]